# "No such file or directory" when trying to open hostapd control connection via wpa_ctrl_open

Tags: c, hostapd

I have configured a control interface for hostapd on embedded Linux like this in the configuration file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
```

I can see that a file is created in the file system:

```
ls -la /var/run/hostapd/wifi_ap0
srwxrwx---    1 root     root             0 Jul 17 20:40 /var/run/hostapd/wifi_ap0
```

However when I try to open a connection to this interface via `wpa_ctrl_open("/var/run/hostapd/wifi_ap0")` it returns `NULL` and `strerror(errno)` returns `No such file or directory`.

Clearly the file exists, so I don't understand what is wrong here. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hostapd_cli -r -a <command>
```

-a start as daemon and -r try to reconnect to hostapd socket.

I had same problem and it was sufficient to add -r
Because I start hostapd_cli as service to open a Fotinet vpn every time the client is connected.